# PrimeFaces DataGrid Paginator is having a 'P' word inside Hidden Css

Tags: primefaces, datagrid

i am getting this weird thingy by using the primefaces datagrid, what i did is just modify the css by changing the paginator from center to right. How can i removed the "P" word?

[paginator for the dataGrid primefaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoaRk.png)

[HTML from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCi58.png)

[html for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY0tX.png)

Comment: Please, do not post code in images. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of PF have these characters in the paginator without them (normally) being visible.

In the [6.2 version in the showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml) the client-side html of the paginator looks like this:

```
<div id="form:cars_paginator_bottom" class="ui-paginator ui-paginator-bottom ui-widget-header ui-corner-bottom" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
    <span class="ui-paginator-current">(1 of 4)</span> <a href="#" class="ui-paginator-first ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" aria-label="First Page" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first">F</span>
    </a><a href="#" class="ui-paginator-prev ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" aria-label="Previous Page" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev">P</span>
    </a>
    <span class="ui-paginator-pages">
        <a class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" href="#" aria-label="Page 1">1</a><a class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" href="#" aria-label="Page 2">2</a><a class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" href="#" aria-label="Page 3">3</a><a class="ui-paginator-page ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" href="#" aria-label="Page 4">4</a>
    </span><a href="#" class="ui-paginator-next ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-label="Next Page" tabindex="0">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next">N</span>
    </a><a href="#" class="ui-paginator-last ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-label="Last Page" tabindex="0">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end">E</span>
    </a>
    <label id="form:cars:j_id3_rppLabel" for="form:cars:j_id3" class="ui-paginator-rpp-label ui-helper-hidden">Rows Per Page</label>
    <select id="form:cars:j_id3" name="form:cars_rppDD" aria-labelledby="form:cars:j_id3_rppLabel" class="ui-paginator-rpp-options ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left" value="12" autocomplete="off">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="12" selected="selected">12</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

They are F(irst), P(revious), N(ext) and E(nd). Easy to check by yourself. Remarkable thing here is that you have a 'p' with the next. So most likely you are using an old(er) PF verion.

And since they are not visible there, just the icons, I'm almost 100% sure it is theming (css) related. So there are two options:

- If you are using custom CSS, remove all that and see if it is still a problem. If not, start investigating which part of the custom css messes this up.
- If you are not using custom css or it is still a problem when all custom css is removed **and** you are using a (commercial) PF theme, report there.

Answer (score 0):

"P" is hardcoded in PrimeFaces renderers and it's making trouble to me also... I want to drop "default" images/icons from Cupertino and insert PrimeIcons. This class below basicaly take hardcoded String from `org.primefaces.component.api.UIData` class, for let's say "First page" linkClass is "ui-icon-seek-first", find "seek-", and make next character capital letter. :)

```
public class PageLinkRenderer {

    public void render(FacesContext context, Pageable pageable, String linkClass, String iconClass, boolean disabled, String ariaLabel) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        String styleClass = disabled ? linkClass + " ui-state-disabled" : linkClass;
        int textIndex = iconClass.indexOf("seek-");
        String text = String.valueOf(iconClass.charAt(textIndex + 5)).toUpperCase();
        String tabindex = (disabled) ? "-1" : "0";

        writer.startElement("a", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("href", "#", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, null);
        writer.writeAttribute(HTML.ARIA_LABEL, ariaLabel, null);
        writer.writeAttribute("tabindex", tabindex, null);

        writer.startElement("span", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("class", iconClass, null);
        writer.writeText(text, null);
        writer.endElement("span");

        writer.endElement("a");
    }
}
```

If you take a look at PrimeFaces 7.0 showcase, they use theme with PrimeIcons, and you can inspect their CSS in developers tools to see what they did to avoid letters. First thing they did, they set all `<SPAN>` elements in page navigators to `display:none` so i guess i'll go along the same path.

Try to do something with parent anchor element ('ui-paginator-prev','ui-paginator-last' etc.), i'm not CSS expert so dunno if there is workaround with "classic" icons/images. With vector graphics i'll try to use `:before` CSS on anchor.

Comment: P.S. You can also override PrimeFaces renderer but that could be risky.